# Loop through nested list as flat list

Tags: c#

Title may not be the clearest. I apologise for that.

Imagine I have a List of Comments. Each comment is able to have its own list of comments (comment replies), and each comment reply can have its own list of comment replies, and so on.

It would look a little like this:

`Comment1: Wow, that's cool
 |-Comment1.1: No, it's not. You're stupid.
 |-|-Comment1.1.1: Why the flame?
 |-Comment1.2: Yeah, I agree!
 Comment2: I like horses
 |-Comment2.1: Offtopic.
 |-|-Comment2.1.1: Does it really matter?`

It clearly has a parent-child sort of tree thing going on. But say I don't know how many levels each comment goes. How do I loop over each of the comments, as if it were a flat 1 dimensional array?

Comment: Recursion might be one way.

Comment: Oh, true. I haven't thought about recursion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure is called a tree and what you are asking is known as "walking the tree". There are many ways to do this of which recursion is an interesting option.

You will have to supply more information like what data structures you have the tree stored as now before you will get a specific answer.

It all boils down to a set of loops which loops over all the children in each branch of the tree.

When you use recursion you write a function with one loop over all the children of the current node, and for each child you call the same function to go over it's children ...

EDIT: Here is a rough example

```
void processNode(TreeNode t)
{
   // Here print it out to print all nodes or add it to an 
   //    ArrayList to just make a list, or whatever you please.
}

void walkTreeNode(TreeNode t)
{
    processNode(t);
    foreach (TreeNode child in t.getChildren())
       walkTreeNode(child);
}
```

Now you just call walkTreeNode with the root of the tree.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to attempt to write a recursion function that will basically:

1. Loop through the array  
2. Inside the array, check if the array contains more arrays  
3. If so, self(that array)

Comment: Should be easy. The function should process only the current node and call "process" on each of it's children, which then repeats until the node has no children.

Comment: So, how would I use this recursive function to write to a new function? Currently I've got this.

`IEnumerable<T> WalkTheTree<T>(IEnumerable<T> c)
        {
            if(c.Count() < 1) return new T[0];
            IEnumerable<T> final;
            foreach(IEnumerable<T> item in c)
            {
                //not all code paths return a value.
                final = WalkTheTree(item);
            }
        }`

edit: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e89428fd8064e129dd5

Comment: I do not think you want to return the node there. You never mentioned what you want to do  with each node. I will edit the question with some pseudo code to illustrate ok?

Comment: Thank you for the example. +1